# Visual Studio Winform designer: Set DataBindings on current control BindingSource

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, data-binding, windows-forms-designer

I am creating a UserControl in Winforms, using Visual Studio 2013 designer. It contains a TextBox. I added a BindingSource (which DataSource property is set in code to a List).

[image]

When I click on the TextBox, look in the property window (F4), expand the "(DataBindings)" node and click on the "(Advanced)" button the Binding window opens.

[image]

In that window, there is no choice available in the Bindings list (beside Add). I Expected to find my BindingSource in that list.

[image]

Is it possible to get my custom BindingSource (added with Drag&Drop in the designer) available in that Binding window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the DataSource property on your BindingSource control, like so:

[image: BindingSource]

Your BindingSource control will now be available in the designer:

[image]

Comment: Thanks to your post, I figured out that in "Add Project Data Source..." of type "object" lies my solution.