# Trigger the visibility of control based on count

Tags: c#, winforms

This is just a generic question related to C# and WinForm..

Is there any way to automatically trigger visibility of a control based on the count..
For example, I have a Boolean count which could be true or false.. If the count is True I need to hide some control and if its false I need to show the control.

Is it possible that changing the value of Boolean control can trigger the visibility function automatically? So that there is no actual call of Show / Hide control.. When the count value changes it automatically triggers the function which checks for the count value and shows/hide the control?

Comment: You could implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface in winforms like this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms229614(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You have a strange idea of ​​naming variables.

Comment: This could also be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315621/implementing-inotifypropertychanged-does-a-better-way-exist

Comment: Post your code where you want to hide your control and when.

Answer (score 0):

At some point, there WILL be a call to `Show()` or `Hide()` or changing `.Visible`.

You can, in the designer, bind the control's .Visible property to the `Count` property (*seriously* reconsider the name for this) on your object. But that will really just pre-write the code for you.

When are you loading your object that has this boolean-count property? You could change the visiblilty of anything you like at that point.

Or, you could change the visiblity when your user edits the object you're presenting.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22349162/visual-studio-winform-designer-set-databindings-on-current-control-bindingsourc