# Change value of data inside databinding before displaying to textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I have the same set up of databindings as this one
[Visual Studio Winform designer: Set DataBindings on current control BindingSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22349162/visual-studio-winform-designer-set-databindings-on-current-control-bindingsourc)

But I don't know how to change the value of let's say I have 2 models:

```
class Receipt {
   public int ProductId { get; set; }
   public double Price { get; set; }
   //etc...
}

class Product {
   public int ProductId { get; set; }
   public string ProductName { get; set; }
   //etc...
}
```

My datagrid shows the Receipt model and when one is selected, my textboxes shows other details which are not displayed in the datagrid.

Now my problem is I need to display on my text box the ProductName instead of the ProductId.

I am using Entity Framework Code First.
Please help...

TIA.

Comment: You should have some way to get the product instance using the ProductId from Receipt selected.
If you are using SQL, you should select the product from it.

Comment: Do you use Entity Framework?

Comment: @RezaAghaei - Yes, I'm using Code-First

Comment: When you load your `Receipt` load its `Product` too. Then you can simply use its `Product.ToString()` or bind the `TextBox` to its `Product.ProductName`

Comment: Let me know if you have any question about the answer :)

Comment: Are you trying to display two different models in the same data grid?

Comment: @bit2know The OP is trying to show the list of `Receipt` in the `DataGridView` and when he click on a row, show Receipt.Product.ProductName in a `TextBox` using data-binding.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Hi! Sorry, I always forget to get back to this topic.. Sorry about that... As for your posted solution, I didn't tried doing that because my colleague suggested me to redesign my 'Receipt' model and create a 'view-table' where it selects the product name.. But still, your posted looks fine so I will upvote it instead

Comment: No problem :)  You can use a view as you described. Also you can use the solution that I described that is tested and works properly. 
Anyway this question deserves to have an answer and once you may want to make the answer more useful for future readers by voting and accepting. Thank you for your feedback :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Entity Framework and you have `Product` property in `Receipt` class, you can load `Product` with `Receipt`, for example this way:

```
this.receiptBindingSource.DataSource = db.Receipt.Include("Product").ToList();
```

You can set the databinding of your `TextBox` to bind to `Product.ProductName` property using the designer or code:

```
this.textBox1.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", 
                               this.receiptBindingSource, "Product.ProductName", true));
```